# Designer PDF Viewer

Tags: c++

This is my solution for a hackerrank problem but I am getting **segmentation fault** on it and I am unable to identify what is the problem .please help!
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-pdf-viewer/problem?isFullScreen=true

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>v;
    char s[10];
    string str;
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }
vector<int>k;
```

the remaining part of code is below.these are all conditions

```
cin>>str;
        int len=str.length();
        strcpy(s, str.c_str());
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(s[i]=='a'){
                k.push_back(v[1]);
            }
        

else if(s[i]=='b'){
                k.push_back(v[2]);
            }
```

like above piece of code .i put condition for very character and pushback the number.
(StackOverflow not allowing to put complete code so i just put a sample of code)
then i try to find the max element in the vector k

```
int max=*max_element(k.begin(), k.end());
        cout<<max*len;
        return 0;
    }
```

help me in identifying the problem

Comment: Change this: `cin>>v[i];` to this: `cin>>v.at(i);`.  What is the error in this case?  I bet it's a `std::out_of_range` exception, which explains the segmentation fault.

Comment: Also, websites like hackerrank are not there to teach C++.  They assume that you know the language you will be using to answer their questions, and well-enough to not make simple errors as the one you're making here.

Comment: You are using `cin >> v[i]` but `v[i]` is not allocated now. You can resize vector `v` or use `v.push_back` instead.

Comment: `k.push_back(v[1]);` -- The strange thing is that you used `push_back` here, but failed to do that in the code I pointed out.